# Create a register of persons with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, indexing

How can I create a register of persons who are mentioned in my PDFLaTeX document?
I want to write

```
The screwdriver was turned by \person[Mr.]{Miller}.
```

> ```
> The screwdriver was turned by M. Miller.
>
> Register of Persons
> ===================
> Prof. Dr. M. Miller, University of M (p. 4, 12)
> Dr. A. Foobar, University of M (p. 5)
>
> B. Foo, University of Z (p. 1)
> ```

It would be nice, if the persons could be sorted by

1. affiliation
2. last name
3. first name

Comment: It is not clear why you need a solution using BibLaTeX. Except for the title, your question doesn't refer to it _at all_. Requiring solutions like this may severely restrict the possible solutions.

Comment: What would you suggest instead?

Comment: I suggested the `nameauth` package in a previous incarnation of your question. There may be different solutions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a proof of concept in `BibLaTeX` (Edited to include links and pageref in the list of names)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref} % to activate hyperlinks
\usepackage[sorting=affiliation,backref=]{biblatex}  % persons are sorted on their affiliation
%\usepackage[sorting=first,backref]{biblatex}% persons are sorted on their first name
%\usepackage[sorting=last,backref]{biblatex} % persons are sorted on their last name

\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{person}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name,skipout=false]{name}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal,skipout=false]{affiliation,mysortkey}  
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[person]{name,affiliation,mysortkey}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
% Encoding: UTF8
@person{goedel,
  name = {Gödel, Kurt},
  affiliation = {Princeton}
  }
@person{lamport,
  name = {Lamport, Leslie},
  affiliation = {Microsoft}
  }
@person{knuth,
  name = {Knuth, Donald},
  affiliation = {Stanford}
}
\end{filecontents}


\DeclareFieldFormat{affiliation}{#1}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{person}{
\printnames{name}
\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}
\printfield{affiliation}
\usebibmacro{pageref}
}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=name, final]
      \step[fieldset=mysortkey, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldsource=mysortkey,
        match=\regexp{\s*(.+)\s*,\s*(.+)\s*},
        replace={$2$1}]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareSortingScheme{affiliation}{
  \sort{
    \field{affiliation}
  }
}

\DeclareSortingScheme{last}{
  \sort{
    \field{name}
  }
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    backrefpage  = {p\adddot},
    backrefpages = {pp\adddot},
}

\DeclareSortingScheme{first}{
  \sort{
    \field{mysortkey}
  }
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\person}
    {\printfield{postnote}}
    {\setunit{\addspace}\bibhyerref{\printnames{name}}}
    {, }
    {}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\person{knuth}

\newpage

This is page \thepage

\person{goedel} proved the incompleteness theorem. 

The inventor of \TeX{} is \person[Prof.]{knuth}

The \LaTeX{} format was written by \person{lamport} 

\printbibliography[title={List of Names}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The first step is to create a data model for the "registry of names".

```
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{person}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name,skipout=false]{name}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal,skipout=false]{affiliation,mysortkey}  
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[person]{name,affiliation,mysortkey}
```

For the data model we create a new entry type `person` whose fields are `name, affiliation` and the `mysortkey`. The data model must resides in a datamodel file or a configuration file.

The second step is to create a bibliography driver for `person` and formatting instructions for the new fields:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{affiliation}{#1}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{person}{
\printnames{name}
\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}
\printfield{affiliation}
\usebibmacro{pageref}
}
```

The third step is to create sorting instructions, for `affiliation` and last name, this is can be done by simple sorting schemes

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{affiliation}{
  \sort{
    \field{affiliation}
  }
}

\DeclareSortingScheme{last}{
  \sort{
    \field{name}
  }
}
```

For sorting based on the first name we have manipulate the names (maybe `Biber` and `BibLaTeX` have better way to do it, but I was not able to find it  in the documentation):

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=name, final]
      \step[fieldset=mysortkey, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldsource=mysortkey,
        match=\regexp{\s*(.+)\s*,\s*(.+)\s*},
        replace={$2$1}]
    }
  }
}
```

We can use the `Biber` feature to dynamically manipulated `bib` entries to create new fields and new values for them.  Here we duplicate the value of `name` and transform its content (when in standard `BibTeX` format `<last>, <first>` to create the string `<first><last>` in the `mysortkey` field. After this step we can use a simple sorting schema

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{first}{
  \sort{
    \field{mysortkey}
  }
}
```

The final step is to create a citation command `\person`

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\person}
   {\printfield{postnote}}
   {\setunit{\addspace}\bibhyperref{\printnames{name}}}
   {, }
   {}
```

You need BibLaTex > 2.0 and biber > 1.2. This example will work in TeXLive2012

**EDIT**

To print only the initials in the text, the first step is to create a new formatting directive for names, namely:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{firstinit}{\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
```

then, the new formatting directive has to be used (as a format option in the definition of the command for the citation, i.e., `\person`:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\person}
  {\printfield{postnote}}
  {\setunit{\addspace}\bibhyperref{\printnames[firstinit]{name}}}
  {, }
  {}
```

Comment: I get here `ERROR: Package biblatex Error: Option 'sorting=affiliation' invalid.` perhaps my TeX-Live 2009 on debian stable is too old for this.

Comment: Very likely. You need `BibLaTex` > 2.0 and `biber` > 1.2.

Comment: @JonasStein It is easy to add reference and back references.  See the edited version.

Comment: I upgraded to TeXLive 2012 and changed your code a bit it compiles now. Is it difficult to print only the first letter in the text like `K. Gödel prooved...`

Comment: @JonasStein It's better to edit your question (or posting and answer) rather than modifying the answers. It might be good for your case but break down in other people's uses or it might be something that Guido did not wish to include. .

Comment: OK, I will wait for Guidos hints then. Thank you.