# Citing from an Encyclopedia with sub voce

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing, biber

I would like to cite from an encyclopedia. My advisor would like me to use s.v. (see 1. example here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S._v. ).

I am currently using

```
@incollection
```

but adding s.v. to the

```
TITLE=
```

will wrongly put it between the quotation marks.

Is there a better suited bibtex template? I am using biber with biblatex

**Update** MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end {document}
```

```
@incollection{BAR60,
        Author={Foo Bar},
        Title={s.v. Baz},
        Year={1960},
        Booktitle={Encyclopaedia of Everything}
}
```

How should it look like:

Bar, Foo (1960) s.v. "Baz". In: *Encyclopaedia of Everything*

Comment: The combination of biblatex and biber allows you to create your own entry types and fields. See Section 4.5.3 of the manual, and you can create specialised drivers for such entries. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79384/16895 for an example of how to do it.

Comment: Which manual?  The link you provided looks like a lot of work, i am hoping for a simpler solution

Comment: Which `biblatex` style do you use? (This is best answered with an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) whowing the status quo.) What would you like your "s.v." citations to to look like? Note that for your "s.v." citations you probably want to use `@inreference` and not `@incollection`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you use the special type `@inreference` that is specifically for dictionaries and encyclopaedias.

```
@inreference{BAR60,
  author    = {Foo Bar},
  title     = {Baz},
  year      = {1960},
  booktitle = {Encyclopaedia of Everything},
}
```

Then you can just do

```
\NewBibliographyString{subvoce}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  subvoce = {s\adddot v\adddot},
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{title}{%
  \bibstring{subvoce}\addabbrvspace\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
```

to automatically add the "s.v." to the title.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{subvoce}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  subvoce = {s\adddot v\adddot},
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{title}{%
  \bibstring{subvoce}\addabbrvspace\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inreference{BAR60,
  author    = {Foo Bar},
  title     = {Baz},
  year      = {1960},
  booktitle = {Encyclopaedia of Everything},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{BAR60}
\printbibliography
\end {document}
```

If you want the 's.v.' to remain in lowercase at all times, you can sprinkle in a `\midsentence`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{title}{%
  \midsentence\bibstring{subvoce}\addabbrvspace\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
```