# How to cite an entry in a multivolume encyclopedia?

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, citing

How do I cite the entry *religion* in the volume 12 of a multi-volume encyclopedia called "Encyclopedia of Religion"?

Moreover, it'd be nice to know how to cite other entries in the other volumes of the same encyclopedia by using the cross-referencing technique.

All the instructions I've found so far have been quite hard to understand.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you actually use `biblatex`? What style do you use? What would you like the citation and bibliography entries to look like? Please prepare an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that answers all of these questions. An answer will crucially depends on the answers to these questions. Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290695/35864

Comment: Yes, I use biblatex ( \usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex} ) The style is article.

Comment: I mean the `biblatex` style (`style=`), not the `\documentclass`. And what output would you like to see?

Comment: References are footcites according to the setting verbose-ibid.. Hopefully, this clarifies my question!

Comment: It still does not tell me the output you expect to see, but if you have no particular output in mind, you'll have to live with what I come up with.

Comment: Please, just give me an example of how you'd do it. I try and see whether your example works or not in my case. If not, I'll tweak it until I've come up with a workaround I can live with :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For entries in encyclopedias the type `@inreference` is what you are looking for. You can use `@mvreference` for the encyclopedia that contains the entry, they can be linked with `crossref`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, backend=biber, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvreference{eor,
  title     = {Encyclopedia of Religion},
  edition   = {2},
  volumes   = {15},
  date      = {2005},
  publisher = {Macmillan},
  location  = {Detroit},
  editor    = {Jones, Lindsay},
  options   = {useeditor=false},
}
@inreference{eor:religion,
  author     = {Winston L. King},
  title      = {Religion [first edition]},
  shorttitle = {Religion},
  volume     = {11},
  pages      = {7692-7701},
  crossref   = {eor},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

\begin{document}
\autocite{eor:religion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers, works like a charm :) And your example is so clear that it's almost self-explanatory!