# 'condensed' bibliography for Encyclopedia references, but detailed citations?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

So, I've been eyeballing [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428511/how-to-cite-an-entry-in-a-multivolume-encyclopedia) but it doesn't quite get what I'm wanting.
I'd like to get

`Encyclopaedia Britannica, Vol. 2, “Babylonia and Assyria,” p. 849`

in the footnote/endnote from `\autocite[849]{britannica:babyloniaandassyria}` and so
on for other articles in other volumes and pages but only have

`Encyclopaedia Britannica, Encyclopedia Britannica, Inc., Chicago, 1943, 175th Anniversary Edition`

in the final `\printbibliography` output.

So, specific details in the citation itself, but just the whole encyclopaedia in the bibliography. Is this possible without an extreme amount of fnagling?

Current bib file snippet.

```latex
\documentclass[english,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[citestyle=authortitle-ibid,backend=biber,ibidpage=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvreference{encyclopaedia:britannica,
    address = {Chicago},
    author = {{Encyclopedia Britannica, Inc.}},
    edition = {175th Anniversary Edition},
    options = {useeditor=false},
    title = {Encyclopaedia Britannica},
    volumes = {24},
    year = {1943}
}

@inreference{britannica:babyloniaandassyria,
    crossref = {encyclopaedia:britannica},
    title = {Babylonia and Assyria},
    volume = {2},
}

@inreference{britannica:david,
    crossref = {encyclopaedia:britannica},
    title = {David},
    volume = {7},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

\begin{document}

    \autocite[849]{britannica:babyloniaandassyria}
    \autocite[75]{britannica:david}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Results in:
[image: results]

Comment: A solution here will depend on the bibliography and citation style you are using. Please share a small example document with us that reproduces your bibliography and citation setup. That way we're all on the same page.

Comment: as in, the latex behind it? its pretty much exactly the same as the linked question but sure, I'll post a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a source map and use the options `skipbib` and `skiplab` for the entries with `crossref` equal to `encyclopaedia:britannica`.

From [BibLaTeX manual](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf):

> `skipbib=true, false` default: `false` If this option is enabled, the
> entry is excluded from the bibliography but it may still be cited.
> This option is also settable on a per-type basis.
>
> `skiplab=true, false` default: `false` If this option is enabled,
> `biblatex` will not assign any labels to the entry. It is not required
> for normal operation. Use it with care. If enabled, `biblatex` can not
> guarantee unique citations for the respective entry and citations
> styles which require labels may fail to create valid citations for the
> entry. This option is also settable on a per-type basis.

```
\documentclass[english,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[citestyle=authortitle-ibid,backend=biber,ibidpage=false]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvreference{encyclopaedia:britannica,
    address = {Chicago},
    author = {{Encyclopedia Britannica, Inc.}},
    edition = {175th Anniversary Edition},
    options = {useeditor=false},
    title = {Encyclopaedia Britannica},
    volumes = {24},
    year = {1943}
}

@inreference{britannica:babyloniaandassyria,
    crossref = {encyclopaedia:britannica},
    title = {Babylonia and Assyria},
    volume = {2},
    options      = {skipbib}
}

@inreference{britannica:david,
    crossref = {encyclopaedia:britannica},
    title = {David},
    volume = {7},
    options      = {skipbib}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{ 
      \step[fieldsource=crossref,
        match={encyclopaedia:britannica},
        fieldset=options,
        fieldvalue={skipbib,skiplab}]
    }
  }
}
 
\begin{document}
    \autocite[849]{britannica:babyloniaandassyria}
    \autocite[75]{britannica:david}
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very good, but a small other nit. Doable to have instead of 'Encyclopedia Britannica, Inc.' simply 'Encyclopedia Britannica', along with \emph-asis?

Comment: @hanetzer try with `author = {{\textit{Encyclopedia Britannica}}}` in the reference `encyclopaedia:britannica`.