# Custom formatting for @inreference type

Tags: biblatex

For a paper I need to adopt a citation style for encyclopedia references that looks completely different from other sources (eg monographs, collections):

```
<LastName>, <FirstName>, Art. <ArticleTitle>, in: <Encyclopedia>^<Edition> <Volume> (<Year>), <Pages>.
```

Is this possible using BibLatex? I have the rest of the document working ok, so the solution would need to work for just this entry type.

In the document I'm using `style=ext-verbose-inote` with some modifications:

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,12pt, parskip=half, pointednumbers]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[left=25mm, right=50mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\onehalfspacing 

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ext-verbose-inote,
    autocite=footnote,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    innamebeforetitle=true,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}


\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{#1}
    {\setunit*{\locdatedelim}}
    {\setunit*{\locpubdelim}}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\pubdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}


\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}


\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addspace\slash\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}


\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{booktitle}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{booktitle}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{\textsuperscript{#1}} 

  \DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman} {% 
      andothers = {et al.},               % "et al." statt "u. a." 
      editor = {\mkbibparens{Hg.\adddot}},   % Hrsg. in Klammern 
      editors = {\mkbibparens{Hg.\adddot}}    % Hrsg. in Klammern 
      } 




\begin{document} 

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{spacing}{1}   
   \centering 
    Some Text
  \end{spacing} 
\end{titlepage} 

\newpage 
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
% TEXT BEGINNT HIER
\section{Introduction}
\section{Part 1}
\subsection{Section}
\subsection{Section}
\subsection{Section}
Testtext\Footcite[Vgl.][100-105]{kampf}
\subsection{Section}
Testext\Footcite[Vgl.][]{dbwnf}\Footcite[Vgl.][]{nachfolge}\Footcite[Vgl.][100-200]{rgggnade}
\section{Schluss}

\newpage 
\printbibliography[keyword=pl, title={Primärliteratur}]
\printbibliography[keyword=sl, title={Sekundärliteratur}]
\end{document}
```

Bib file for reference:

```
@inreference{rgggnade,
    Author = {Saarinen, Risto},
    Booktitle = {RGG},
    Date-Modified = {2019-08-04 19:13:13 +0200},
    Edition = {4},
    Keywords = {sl},
    Title = {Gnade/Gnade Gottes. V. Systematisch-theologisch},
    Volume = {3},
    Year = {2000}}

@book{nachfolge,
    Address = {Stuttgart},
    Author = {Liebend{\"o}rfer, Bernd},
    Date-Added = {2019-08-04 17:32:06 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2019-08-04 17:45:58 +0200},
    Keywords = {sl},
    Title = {Der Nachfolge-Gedanke Dietrich Bonhoeffers und seine Potentiale in der Gegenwart},
    Year = {2016}}

@book{kampf,
    Address = {Osnabr{\"u}ck},
    Author = {Schlegel, Thomas and Schwarze, Andreas},
    Date-Added = {2019-08-04 16:53:38 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2019-08-04 16:57:04 +0200},
    Keywords = {sl},
    Subtitle = {Studien zu Dietrich Bonhoeffer},
    Title = {Der Kampf um die teure Gnade},
    Year = {2002}}

@incollection{dbwnf,
    Address = {M{\"u}nchen},
    Author = {Dietrich Bonhoeffer},
    Booktitle = {Dietrich Bonnhoeffer Werke (DBW 4)},
    Date-Added = {2019-08-04 14:01:21 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2019-08-04 17:31:25 +0200},
    Editor = {Kuske, Martin and T{\"o}dt, Ilse},
    Keywords = {pl},
    Title = {Nachfolge},
    Year = {1989}}
```

Comment: Do you have an example `@inreference` entry for us? We don't have your `literatur.bib` and so don't get to see your `kampf`, `nachfolge` and `rgggnade` entries.

Comment: Very mildly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290695/35864

Comment: I had a look at that previously. While changing field format works fine, I suppose what I need is to change the delimiters conditional on the entry type.

Answer (score 1):

Usually `@inreference` is an alias for `@incollection`, but the desired output is so different from `@incollection` that it makes sense to define a new bibliography driver that is specifically tailored to produce the desired output.

`\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inreference}` is just a copy of [`\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}` (ll. 338-369 in v0.7a of `ext-standard.bbx`)](https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/blob/946e3bca894af9878b08e11c4266093c925715e4/ext-standard.bbx#L338-L369) with `incollection` replaced by `inreference`. `inreference:parent` does all the heavy lifting.

An `@inreference` entry should almost always have a `@pages` field, so I added one. I also slightly reordered the definitions to make it easier for me to keep track of what is going on and modified some small things. (There is, for example, no need for `sortlocale=de_DE,` if you load `babel` with the document language `ngerman`).

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,12pt, parskip=half, numbers=enddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-verbose-inote,
  autocite=footnote,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  natbib=true,
  url=false,
  doi=true,
  eprint=false,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addspace\slash\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection,inbook,book]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{title}{\bibstring{article}~#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection,inbook]{booktitle}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat[reference,inreference]{date}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{#1}
    {\setunit*{\locdatedelim}}
    {\setunit*{\locpubdelim}}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\pubdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inreference}{%
  \usebibmacro{introcite:plain}%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{crosscite}{inreference:parent}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{isbn}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:related} and not test {\iffieldxref{related}}}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\newbibmacro*{inreference:parent}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:innamebeforetitle}
    {\usebibmacro{in:editor+others}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{innametitledelim}}\newblock}
    {}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{booktitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{booksubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[booktitle]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{booktitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{booksubtitle}}%
     \setunit{}%
     \printfield[superedition]{edition}}%
  \printfield{booktitleaddon}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{part}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printdate}


\NewBibliographyString{article}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  article   = {Art\adddot},
  andothers = {et al\adddot},
  editor    = {Hg\adddot},
  editors   = {Hg\adddot},
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inreference{rgggnade,
  author    = {Saarinen, Risto},
  booktitle = {RGG},
  edition   = {4},
  keywords  = {sl},
  title     = {Gnade/Gnade Gottes. V. Systematisch-theologisch},
  volume    = {3},
  year      = {2000},
  pages     = {100-103},
}
@book{nachfolge,
  address  = {Stuttgart},
  author   = {Liebendörfer, Bernd},
  keywords = {sl},
  title    = {Der Nachfolge-Gedanke Dietrich Bonhoeffers
              und seine Potentiale in der Gegenwart},
  year     = {2016},
}
@book{kampf,
  address  = {Osnabrück},
  author   = {Schlegel, Thomas and Schwarze, Andreas},
  keywords = {sl},
  subtitle = {Studien zu Dietrich Bonhoeffer},
  title    = {Der Kampf um die teure Gnade},
  year     = {2002},
}
@incollection{dbwnf,
  address   = {München},
  author    = {Dietrich Bonhoeffer},
  booktitle = {Dietrich Bonnhoeffer Werke (DBW 4)},
  editor    = {Kuske, Martin and Tödt, Ilse},
  keywords  = {pl},
  title     = {Nachfolge},
  year      = {1989},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Testtext\Autocite[Vgl.][100-105]{kampf}
Testext\Autocite[Vgl.][]{dbwnf}
dolor\Autocite[Vgl.][]{nachfolge}
sit\Autocite[Vgl.][100-200]{rgggnade}

\printbibliography[keyword=pl, title={Primärliteratur}]
\printbibliography[keyword=sl, title={Sekundärliteratur}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Saarinen, Risto, Art. Gnade/Gnade Gottes. V. Systematisch-theologisch, in: RGG 4 Bd. 3 (2000), S. 100–103.]